# Mass-assigning link attributes based on proximity

Tags: jquery, dom

I've got this little piece of code which works a treat:

```
var r_link = $(".link_article a");
var j_link = $(r_link).closest(".row").find(".read-more a");
var attributes = r_link.prop("attributes");
$.each(attributes, function() {
  j_link.attr(this.name, this.value);
});
```

All's well and good other than the fact that it doesn't get the links' attributes based on proximity, the end result of which being that all the `j_link`s on the page have the same link and not the different ones they should. I can't access the `j_links` to give them IDs.

Any thoughts? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over `r_link`

Try this

```
var r_link = $(".link_article a");

r_link.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var j_link = $this.closest(".row").find(".read-more a");
    j_link.attr('href', this.href);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't like that. That breaks it.

Comment: Need to change the tools from MooTools to jQuery, it would seem.

Comment: Even so `name` and `value` attributes are missing from the links in the first case

Comment: Wouldn't they be the `name` and `value` of the attributes themselves?

Comment: What do you mean by attributes here , `<span class="read-more"><a href="#">Link</a></span>` is the `anchor tag` in question and it has only `href` attribute

Comment: By attributes I mean the `href` of the `anchor`.

Comment: If thats the case `j_link.attr(this.name, this.value);` supposed to be `j_link.attr('href', this.href);`

Comment: That works great! I've got the `data-remote="true"` attribute in the `anchor` as well: is there a way to bring that across too?

Comment: you can use `$this.data('remote')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(...
   j_link.eq(i).attr(...)
```

[Documentation for `.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)